# VB.NET INSERT @SET & Query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

am pretty stuck in doing this correctly so let me explain this :

I want to insert this query and it will be changed all the time by textboxes ( their values etc.. and it got @SET )

```
SET
@entry= 19000,
@displayid= '2727',
@name= 'World Of Wacraft Item',
@description= 'This is just a testing Item',
@allowableclass= '2',
@allowablerace= '2',
@delay= 1000,
@RequiredLevel= 85,
@ItemLevel= 255,
@maxcount= 1,
@dmg_type1= 0,
@dmg_type2= 0,
@Armor= 2540,
@itemset= 232,
@Quality= 5,
@Flags = 0,
@dmg_min1= 0,
@dmg_min2= 0,
@dmg_max1= 0,
@dmg_max2= 0,
@class= 4,
@subclass = 4,
@socketBonus= 3312,
@socketColor_1= 4,
@socketColor_2= 1,
@socketColor_3= 8,
@fire_res= 52,
@holy_res= 33,
@nature_res= 25,
@shadow_res= 52,
@frost_res= 24,
@arcane_res= 65,
@StatsCount= 10,
@InventoryType= 1,
@stat_type1= 6,
@stat_type2= 7,
@stat_type3= 4,
@stat_type4= 13,
@stat_type5= 47,
@stat_type6= 31,
@stat_type7= 0,
@stat_type8= 0,
@stat_type9= 0,
@stat_type10= 0,
@stat_value1= 8567,
@stat_value2= 687658,
@stat_value3= 4756,
@stat_value4= 868,
@stat_value5= 6365,
@stat_value6= 4841,
@stat_value7= 0,
@stat_value8= 0,
@stat_value9= 0,
@stat_value10= 0;

INSERT INTO item_template (entry, displayid, Name, description, allowableclass, allowablerace, delay, requiredlevel, itemlevel, maxcount, dmg_type1, dmg_type2, armor, itemset, quality, flags, dmg_min1, dmg_min2, dmg_max1, dmg_max2, class, subclass, socketbonus, socketcolor_1, socketcolor_2, socketcolor_3, fire_res, holy_res, nature_res, shadow_res, frost_res, arcane_res, statscount, inventorytype, stat_type1, stat_type2, stat_type3, stat_type4, stat_type5, stat_type6, stat_type7, stat_type8, stat_type9, stat_type10, stat_value1, stat_value2, stat_value3, stat_value4, stat_value5, stat_value6, stat_value7, stat_value8, stat_value9, stat_value10)
VALUES 
(@entry, @displayid,
@name, @description,
@allowableclass, @allowablerace,
@delay, @RequiredLevel, @ItemLevel,
@maxcount, @dmg_type1, @dmg_type2,
@armor, @itemset, @quality, @flags,
@dmg_min1, @dmg_min2, @dmg_max1, @dmg_max2,
@class, @subclass, @socketbonus,
@socketColor_1, @socketColor_2, @socketColor_3,
@fire_res, @holy_res, @nature_res, @shadow_res,
@frost_res, @arcane_res,
@StatsCount, @InventoryType, @stat_type1,
@stat_type2, @stat_type3, @stat_type4,
@stat_type5, @stat_type6, @stat_type7,
@stat_type8, @stat_type9, @stat_type10,
@stat_value1, @stat_value2, @stat_value3,
@stat_value4, @stat_value5, @stat_value6,
@stat_value7, @stat_value8,
@stat_value9, @stat_value10);
```

And this result will appear in textbox called = outputsql.text

So this is the VB.NET code

```
 Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server =" + TextBox1.Text + ";userid=" + TextBox3.Text + ";password=" + TextBox4.Text + ";database=" + TextBox5.Text + ";port=" + TextBox2.Text
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = Outputsql.text
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Can you break down the problem and make it easier for us to help you?

Comment: Like where the problem is, is the problem that your SQL is incorrect, or is the error when you try to execute the query? Or maybe its something else? Also i hope this application is for your use only and not for other users, as you are basically creating a massive security hole by allowing people to enter their own query.

Comment: No you did not explain it very clearly - the Down Votes are telling you that (very clearly).  `am pretty stuck` is not a clear problem statement and `I want` is certainly not a question.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Okey i understand what you mean, okey so the SQL have nothing to do with the error but the problem is the VB code that doesn't accept the @SET So also it's for everyone use and it actually generate the SQL for them so no worries about any mistakes as it won't be only if they mean to do it, so the problem here that when i click the button which will do that code i typed it will give me the error because the query using ATset, what i want is to find the correct way of inserting this type of queries via VB.NET and thanks in advance!

Comment: @JadaDeveloper please [edit] your question to include explanations, instead of adding it in the comments. Comments are ephemeral. They can be deleted without trace at any time. Also people on stack exchange are not expected to read the comments on a post to be able to answer it. As such, you should include all context **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest using the SQLConnectionString Builder to avoid malicious injection attacks.

```
Dim sb As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
sb.Server = TextBox1.Text
sb.UserID = TextBox3.Text
sb.Password = TextBox4.Text
sb.Database = TextBox5.Text
sb.Port = TextBox2.Text
Using cn As New MySqlConnection(sb.ConnectionString)
```

Next, skip all the Set section and start with the Insert as your command text.

```
Dim query As String = "Insert Into item_template (entry, displayid,.....VALUES (@entry, @displayid,@name, @description,.....@stat_value10);"


Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
```

Then add parameters to for each of your fields your command. This also protects against malicious injection.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@entry", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 19000 'or CInt(TextBox?.Text) or a variable
cmd.Parameters.Add("@display", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "2727" 'or TextBox?.Text or a variable
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "World of Wacraft Item" 'or TextBox?.Text or a variable
```

The Reader is used for retrieving data not insert commands. Use .ExecuteNonQuery for Insert, Update and Delete. This will return rows affected.

```
cn.Open()
Dim ReturnValue As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
cn.Close()


End Using
End Using
```

The Using statements ensure that connection and command objects are properly disposed and resources returned even if there is an error.

Comment: Thank you mary! that would solve my problem i'm sure from what i see that is the correct  way to do it ... i know about it i was just worried if there is another method :/ so well yeah it will work 100% sure!